# Observable patterns for caching and defered data retrieval

Tags: angularjs, caching, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm trying to create a caching function in angular using RxJS Observable. Originally I've created this method using angularjs `$q`'s deferred promise. Observables and RxJS are new to me and I find this method of working still somewhat confusing.

This is my current implementation of a `getOrCreate` caching function. Retrieve a single value for a key from storage (`this.get()`) and if it's not in there you retrieve it elsewhere (`fetcher`).

Assume `fetcher` is a slower data source than `this.get()`. Multiple requests for the same key could fire while we're still retrieving from `this.get()` so I put in an aggregator: only a single observable is created for multiple requests of the same key.

```js
protected observableCache : {[key: string] : Observable<any>} = {};

get<T>(key : string): Observable<T> { /* Async data retrieval */ }

getOrCreate<T>(key : string, fetcher: () => Observable<T>) : Observable<T> {
  const keyHash = this.hash(key);

  // Check if an observable for the same key is already in flight
  if (this.observableCache[keyHash]) {
    return this.observableCache[keyHash];
  } else {

    let observable : Observable<T>;

    this.get(key).subscribe(

      // Cache hit
      (result) => { observable = Observable.of(result); },

      // Cache miss. Retrieving from fetching while creating entry
      () => {
        fetcher().subscribe((fetchedResult) => {
          if(fetchedResult) {
            this.put(key, fetchedResult);
          }
          observable = Observable.of(fetchedResult);
        });
      }
    );


   // Register and unregister in-flight observables
   this.observableCache[keyHash] = observable;
   observable.subscribe(()=> {
      delete this.observableCache[this.hash(key)];
   });

    return observable;
  }
}
```

This is my current version of that code but it doesn't look like I'm properly handling async code:

- Observable will be returned before it's instantiated: `return observable` fires before `observable = Observable.of(result)`;
- There's probably a much better pattern of aggregating all requests for the same key while `this.get()` is still in-flight.

Can someone help with finding the Observer patterns should be used?

Comment: Is `this.get(key)` async? Looks like `this.put(key, fetchedResult)` could use a synchronous Map (maybe you are using some sort of system that makes it async?). If `this.get(key)` was synchronous, it would make it way easier...

Comment: @olivarra1 I'm sorry. `this.get(key)` returns an `Observable<T>`. Consider this to be any data source - from static memory retrieval to an async database lookup.

Comment: `this.observableCache[keyHash] = observable;` : At the moment of evaluation of this statement, `observable` could very much be undefined (if `this.get(key) is async` for example - not all `Observable<T>` emit asynchronously). The evaluation of this `observable.subscribe(()=> {...` could give an error, as there is no `subscribe` method on an undefined variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might work. Rewritten as:

```
getOrCreate<T>(key : string, fetcher: () => Observable<T>) : Observable<T> {
    const keyHash = this.hash(key);

    // Check if an observable for the same key is already in flight
    if (this.observableCache[keyHash]) {
        return this.observableCache[keyHash];
    }

    let observable : ConnectableObservable<T> = this.get(key)
        .catch(() => { // Catch is for when the source observable throws  error: It replaces it with the new Rx.Observable that is returned by it's method
            // Cache miss. Retrieving from fetching while creating entry
            return this.fetchFromFetcher(key, fetcher);
        })
        .publish();

    // Register and unregister in-flight observables
    this.observableCache[keyHash] = observable;
    observable.subscribe(()=> {
        delete this.observableCache[keyHash];
    });
    observable.connect();

    return observable;
},

fetchFromFetcher(key : string, fetcher: () => Observable<T>) : Observable<T> {
    // Here we create a stream that subscribes to fetcher to use `this.put(...)`, returning the original value when done
    return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
        fetcher().subscribe(fetchedResult => {
            this.put(key, fetchedResult);
            observer.next(fetchedResult);
        },
        err => observer.error(err),
        () => observer.complete())
    });
}
```

Explanations:

1. Observables are very different from promises. They are to work with async stuff, and there are some similarities, but they are quite different
2. As `this.get(...)` seems asynchronous, your `let observable` won't get filled until it yields a value, so when you assign it to your cache it's normal that's null.
3. A great thing about observables (and the main difference with promises) is that you can define a stream before anything gets executed. In my solution, nothing gets called until I call `observable.connect()`. This avoids so many .subscriptions
4. So, in my code I get the `this.get(key)` stream, and tell it that if it fails (`.catch(...)`) it must fetch the result, but once that's fetched then put it into your cache (`this.put(key, fetchedResult`)
5. Then I `publish()` this observable: This makes it so it behaves more like promises do, it makes it "hot". This means that all subscribers will get the values from the same stream, instead of creating a new stream that starts from 0 everytime one subscribes to it.
6. Then I store it in the observable pool, and set to delete it when it finishes.
7. Finally, I `.connect()`. This is only done if you `publish()` it, it's the thing that actually subscribes to the original stream, executing everything you want.

To make it clear, because this is a common error coming from Promises, in angular if you define a stream as:

```
let myRequest = this.http.get("http://www.example.com/")
    .map((result) => result.json());
```

The request it's not sent yet. And everytime you do `myRequest.subscribe()`, a new request to the server is made, it won't reuse the "first subscription" result. That's why `.publish()` is very useful: It makes that when you call `.connect()` it creates a subscription that triggers the request, and will share the last result received (Observables support streams: Many results) with all incoming subscriptions to the published observable.

Comment: That is very useful! I didn't know about `.publish()` and `.connect()` yet. It feels a lot like `.publish()` creates a `defered` object and becomes resolved on `.connect()`.

Comment: I'm considering your note on using `.do()` versus `.create()`. Your current version has a logical flow. Could you elaborate how you can subscribe inside create?

Comment: For me it's quite hard to see the similarity of publish/connect to deferred/resolve...  resolve is normally used when the promise has it's value, right? with connect we're just saying to start fetching from the server so it can share the values

Comment: As to the `.create()` inside `.do()`, to avoid too many indentations levels I would do that in another method... Let me edit a bit

Comment: Thanks again. That version is a lot harder to read. I'm assuming the second and third parameter for `.create()` are optional. The documentation for `onNext` vs `next` etc in there is not so clear. I'll stick to the original version and test it all out.

Comment: Yes, it makes it harder to read. But it's considered a best practice not to add side effects inside streams except for logging or inside `subscribe(...)`, although sometimes it compromises readability.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139976/discussion-between-raven-and-olivarra1).